# Как проверить размер экрана?

Tags: android

Как проверить размер экрана? Например,

```
if (дюйм_телефона <= 4){
  (Действие какое-то);
if (дюйм_телефона > 4 && дюйм_телефона <7)
  (Действие какое-то);
else
  (Действие какое-то);
```

Вот хидер, и по размеру телефонов он должен (FrameLayout) высоту увеличивать...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это в коде проверить?

Comment: какое отношение мера длины имеет к программированию?

Comment: Если больше четырех дюймов, то я высоту хидера увеличу... То есть в приложении есть хидер и я должен его динамически увеличивать и уменьшать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте о [поддержке различных размеров экранов в Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) (на русском).

Вкратце: вы делаете разные лейауты, создаете ресурсы с папками соответсвующим разным диапазонам размеров экрана `values-large`, `values-small` и.т.д. Можно создавать свои диапазоны c помощью [классификаторов размеров экрана](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)

Например, `values-w<n>dp` (`values-w720dp`, `values-w1024dp` и.т.п.) определяет минимальную доступную ширину экрана.

И размещаете ссылки на лейауты в соответсвующих разрешению папкам и используете одни и те же имена соотсветсвующие именам ресурсов.

Ну а размеры экрана в дюймах считаются так:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); //метод Activity
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;
int dens=dm.densityDpi;
double wi=(double)width/(double)dens;
double hi=(double)height/(double)dens;
double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

Comment: Ну блин, есть же нормальные люди! Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Ошибка выскакивает на второй строке... Эти методы че так и должны оставаться без присвоения к какому нибудь переменному?

Comment: dm в getMetrics  передается по ссылке и там присваивается. Вы из Activity вызываете?

Comment: Да! Все ошибка исчезла. Но при нажатии хотел сделать чтобы тост выскакивал с сообщение "inch + дюйм"; Не получается Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  screenInches+" дюйм", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();